# Allowing the user to resize text - size is then set across all pages?

Tags: development

I'm wondering if there's a way to have a simple increase/decrease text option in Sharepoint, that doesn't purely rely on Javascript, ie if you set it on one page, any other page you visit will have remembered that setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you'd have to rely on javascript, or cookies atleast to make such functionality work.

You have 3 options here.

1. You can use javascript, which you use to create a cookie and then resize all texts based on that cookies value. The downside of this is that the users might experience lack of performance as javascript doesn't run untill the DOM is done loading.
2. You create a custom control / webpart which you place in the masterpage, which also would have to read a cookie value to make sure it will resize the text at all times.
3. Same as #2, but with a login requirement. This way every time a user logs on to the site, its personal settings will be loaded and the text resized. (*Wouldn't recommend this option though*)

I equally prefer option 1 & 2, as they do the same; One is just client-side as the other is server-side.